# How to perform update for this select query?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

```
select * from xxhys_bill_site_m master, xxhys_bill_site_m_wk wk`
where master.bill_site_cd = wk.name`
and master.co_cd = wk.co_cd`
and SYSDATE between master.CUST_SITE_VALID_START_DT and NVL(master.CUST_SITE_VALID_END_DT,'3999/12/31')`
and master.co_cd NOT IN ('1012','3002','3004','3008','3009','3010','3011','3012','3015','3014','3016','3017,'3018','3019')`
and wk.ifid <> 'SPIJ0679X31';
```

The select query above is quite difficult for me to convert into update statement, I performed such various of update query but not getting the same result from select statement.
I want to update those data being queried by the select statement above.

Comment: Why are you not using standard `JOIN` syntax?  What do you want to update?  Your question is not clear.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would update columns in table xxhys_bill_site_m.
For more info you will need to tell us which columns you wish to update.

```
update xxhys_bill_site_m 
set bill_site_cd = 'update value' 
-- here you will put all the columns you want to update from table xxhys_bill_site_m
-- you will do it in the way I have shown in the code line above
where SYSDATE between xxhys_bill_site_m.CUST_SITE_VALID_START_DT and NVL(xxhys_bill_site_m.CUST_SITE_VALID_END_DT,'3999/12/31')
and xxhys_bill_site_m.co_cd NOT IN ('1012','3002','3004','3008','3009','3010','3011','3012','3015','3014','3016','3017','3018','3019')
and exists (select '1'
            from xxhys_bill_site_m_wk 
            where xxhys_bill_site_m_wk.ifid <> 'SPIJ0679X31'
            and xxhys_bill_site_m_wk.name = xxhys_bill_site_m.bill_site_cd
            and xxhys_bill_site_m_wk.co_cd = xxhys_bill_site_m.co_cd)
```

Comment: Hi @JohnAdamRamos was this answer of help to you ?